# How do I invoke a shell command during a Play 2.0 build (sbt)?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, scala-2.10

I would like to add a symlink from the `.git/hooks` directory to a file in my working tree during a regular Play! framework 2.0 build. According to the Play documentation, all sbt functionality is available as normal in a Play build. Based on google searches, I'm trying to add this code to the ApplicationBuild object in my `project/Build.scala` file:

```
val symlinkGitPrepushHookTask = compile in Compile <<= compile in Compile map {comp =>
  val output = "ln -sf ../../.hooks/pre-push.py .git/hooks/pre-push".!!
  print(output)
  comp
}
```

From my reading of the sbt docs, this should be adding a dependency to the compile task in the Compile scope. The dependency is on its existing value, but with my additional function mapped to it. Now when the compile task runs, my anonymous function should be run too. This does not successfully create the symlink, and does not even seem to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately after posting this, I thought I would try adding the example I had found to the `project/plugins.sbt` file. This works, although it seems an abuse of a file to specify plugins.

```
... existing plugins.sbt content ...

compile in Compile <<= compile in Compile map { comp =>
  "ln -sf ../../.hooks/pre-push.py .git/hooks/pre-push".!!
  comp
}
```

The blank line is critical, as this is the delimiter in the `.sbt` format.